# Apply `lambda` and `map` in looping?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have files named as:

```
'guess-number.py', 'convert-object-to-dict.py'
```

I am going to rename them as :

```
import os
import glob
py_files = glob.glob('*.py')
```

Then rename them:

```
for file in py_files:
    os.rename(file, file.replace('-','_'))

or
des_py_file = [file.replace('-','_') for file in py_file ]
for i, j in zip(py_files, dst_py_files:
    os.rename(i,j)
```

Alternatively I tried functional programming with  `lambda` and `map`

```
map(lambda i,j:os.rename(i,j),zip(py_files,dst_py_files))
or 
map(lambda i: os.rename(i, i.replace('-','_')),py_files)
```

Nothings happens to the files in the directory, while outputs:

```
<map object at 0x109b237f0>
<map object at 0x109b23d30>
```

How to do it with `lambda`?

Comment: Pretty sure you want itertools.starmap in the first case. Regular map takes a function of one arg, which will be a tuple if you use zip.

Comment: Since you don't want an iterator or a list, `map` is the wrong tool.

Comment: Also , you really need that Python 3.x tag.

Comment: @timegb. Map is fine if you feed it through a deque of size zero.

Comment: How to feed it through a seq of of size zero? @MadPhysicist

Comment: @DFK, its deque, pronounced like deck apparently. See the first comment to the accepted answer.

Comment: get it@MadPhysicist

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> How to do it with `lambda`?

Don’t. `map(lambda i,j:os.rename(i,j),zip(py_files,dst_py_files))` is an abuse of `map` for side effects, and, as you’ve noticed, doesn’t work in Python 3 because Python 3’s `map` is evaluated lazily.

You could force its evaluation with `list` or an equivalent to make a useless list like in Python 2:

```
[*map(os.rename, py_files, dst_py_files)]
```

Don’t.

You could force its evaluation with `for`:

```
for _ in map(os.rename, py_files, dst_py_files):
    pass
```

This has the advantage of, uh, .

If you’d really like to pass around functions, though, you can make your own with the explicit purpose of producing side effects:

```
def for_each(action, *iterables):
    for t in zip(*iterables):
        action(*t)


for_each(os.rename, py_files, dst_py_files)
```

Comment: You could force evaluation with `collections.deque(map(...), maxlen=0)`. This would remove side effects but still give an advantage of having an illegible one liner, uh :)

Comment: @MadPhysicist You do live up to your name, don’t you. ;-|

Comment: @MadPhysicist: That *is* cool. It’s still longer than moving the `pass` up to the same line, but since we’re optimizing for creativity…

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ. You wouldn't believe this, but I really did have this happen to me one time. It had to be a map and I just had to run it with no side effects. Someone else wrote the original mess, but it was the most elegant solution at the time.

Comment: @Ryan, I'm not advocating this as a legitimate approach by any means, just wanted to add it in for people that are working with crap code.